# Issue with Worklight Skins laoding on Android tablet

Tags: jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I have developed project using worklight 6.1.0 and using jquery-mobile 1.4.2 for UI Related stuff.
I have also implemented the worklight skins and the changes are reflecting properly. But I have two queries related to it as below :

1)  What is the correct condition to determine whether it is a “Mobile Phone” or a “Tablet” in `getSkinName()` function inside “skinLoader.js”.

2)  When I install the app on the tablet I see that the UI screens do not load properly and sometimes blank screens are shown and sometimes loading icon is displayed continuously on the display. But if I run the same app on the device I don’t face any such issues. Please find attached screenshots for the same error.

Cannot provide source code for the same. Since its confidential.[image]

Attaching the screen shot for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Android is highly fragmented - many different devices and many different resolutions, it is more difficult than with iOS.

I can think of 2 options:

1. have a minimum resolution that you decide to support in your app and check for it.

   This will involves additionally also blocking in the Google Play console to any differences that do not correspond to this size preference.
2. Use the [Cordova device API](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device/blob/master/doc/index.md) to retrieve the device's model and verify it is a model that you support. If you support it, show the tablet design, if not - display an alert and close the app or show some placeholder page, etc...

As for the second question, this requires debugging. Without code, this cannot be answered. Either provide code, or submit this specific question as a PMR to IBM and remove it from this Stack Overflow question.